# More efficient way of finding and pulling out data?

Tags: jquery, traversal

Given this HTML (I realize the srcs & hrefs aren't valid, this is pseudo-code):

```
<div id="featured-story">
    <a href="fullstory">
        <img src="thumbnail" />
    </a>

    <h2><a href="fullstory">Headline</a></h2>
</div>
```

I want to pull various data out. I'm doing so like this:

```
var $featStory = $('#featured-story');
var featHeadline = $featStory.children('h2').text();
var featURL = $featStory.children('h2').children('a').attr('href');
var featImg = $featStory.children('a').children('img').attr('src');
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this? It just seems clunky with all the calls to .children(). (I didn't use .find() because .find() goes infinite levels deep, and I only wanted one level down)

EDIT: and no, there are no IDs are classes I could use as shortcuts, nor do I have control over the HTML being generated.

EDIT 2: hmm, might make more sense to just forget the $featStory var and do this:

```
var featHeadline = $('#featured-story > h2').text();
var featURL = $('#featured-story > h2 > a').attr('href');
var featImg = $('#featured-story > a > img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Orbling's answer however you can actually pass contexts into the selector and keep using your cached selectors like so -

```
var $featStory = $('#featured-story');
var featHeadline = $('h2 a', $featStory).text();
var featURL = $('h2 a', $featStory ).attr('href');
var featImg = $('img', $featStory).attr('src');
```

That should actually be minimally more efficient than redefining your selector.

Comment: Beat me to it. And of course, you can use direct children selectors here as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var featHeadline = $('#featured-story h2 a').text();
var featURL = $('#featured-story h2 a').attr('href');
var featImg = $('#featured-story img').attr('src');
```

Or, for efficiency, you can retain the captured `#featured-story` object.

```
var featStory = $('#featured-story');
var featHeadline = featStory.find('h2 a').text();
var featURL = featStory.find('h2 a').attr('href');
var featImg = featStory.find('img').attr('src');
```

Comment: Yeah I just edited my post to show this. However, keep in mind that "h2 a" will search for anchors infinite levels below h2, while "h2 > a" is just one level down which is what I need.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack: Well I was writing my selectors with your pseudo code as an example, if your layout is different, then so will the selectors be.  I always put classes/IDs on important bits that need selecting and rarely use tags to select because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Add some metadata to your markup so it can be easily serialized into a JSON object.

[data-](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) attributes are great for this, they are arbitrarily named.

```
 <!--
    data-property - denotes the property name
    data-target   - if specified uses the attribute value instead of text()
  -->
<div id="featured-story">
    <a href="fullstory">
        <img data-property="img" data-target="src" src="thumbnail" />
    </a>

    <h2 data-property="headline"><a href="fullstory" data-property="url" data-target="href">Headline</a></h2>
</div>

function serialize(context) {
  var context = $(context).get(0),
      data = {};

  $('*', context).each(function() {
     var property = $(this).data('property');
     if(property  != null) {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        data[property] = target == null : $(this).text() ? $(this).attr(target);
     }
  });

  return data;
}

//usage
var story = serialize('##featured-story');
```

You are probably looking at this and realizing that this has more code than what you started with.. but its very scalable.  You can add in new HTML elements and they'll end up in your object w/o altering your JavaScript at all.  Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Cool solution, but as I said in my original post, I have no control over the HTML being served up. This is 100% front-end.

Comment: It's not included in your original post.  It's included in your first Edit of your original post.  Cheers.